# JaCoCo & Gradle - Filtering Options

Tags: gradle, jacoco, build.gradle

I'm currently using the Gradle plugin to run JaCoCo for code coverage repots. I wanted to specify in my build.gradle some filtering options; https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/wiki/FilteringOptions

I can see that this is possible from the Maven plugin; e.g. https://github.com/timezra/jacoco-scala-maven-plugin

From the Gradle doco [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) there appears no clear way on how to do this.

**How can I set filtering options for JaCoCo when running as part of a `build.gradle` script?**

Comment: are you looking for a `Gradle` solution still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle's JaCoCo plugin doesn't currently provide such filtering options. If you think it should, please file a feature request over at http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: Posted an idea here; http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/jacoco_gradle_plugin_can_we_have_the_ability_to_set_filtering_options_https_github_com_jacoco_jacoco_wiki_filteringoptions